# Pandas DataFrame Slice Column Based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to slice rows in a dataframe column based on conditions- I understand I can assign specific values to rows in my df column based on given conditions using .loc, however I need the condition just to determine how much to slice.

For example, if the row starts with 'A', I would like the first 6 chars ([:6]) whereas if it starts with 'B' I would like it to have the first 8 chars ([:8]).

I am doing this in order to get the data into the correct format before I perform an inner join with another dataframe using pd.merge()

.loc. I can use df.loc[df['column'][:1] == 'A'], but it doesn't give me the index of the rows that satisfy the condition. The best solution I can think of is creating a list of all of the indexes that satisfy the conditions and then manipulating each row one by one. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you mind providing a short code example with a table to display what result you are looking for? Your wording makes it a bit difficult to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with `np.select`

```
m1 = df.col.str[0] == 'A'
m2 = df.col.str[0] == 'B'
df['NewCol'] = np.select([m1, m2], [df.col.str[:6], df.col.str[:8]], default = df.col)
```

Comment: Do you think it may be easier to use np.where() to avoid the m1/m2 initializations?

Comment: @krewsayder I am not sure he only have A and B in the leading char

Comment: Good point.  Assuming it is only a/b would it be more efficient?